# Design-Time Redraw

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, design-time, redraw

I created a custom `listview` control. I set it to add a new button every time I add a new Column. 
When I run the program containing my custom control, the column buttons are placed properly. However, at design time, when I add or remove columns, the control is not updating the added buttons.

They are ok in run-time, but in design time I need to close the form and re-open it (force a re-draw) in order to update the column buttons. 
How can I programmatically force a redraw of my User Control? 

 The Column property looks like this:

```
   <MergableProperty(False)> _
   <Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ColumnHeaderCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", GetType(UITypeEditor))> _
   <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)> _
   <Localizable(True)> _
    Public ReadOnly Property Columns() As ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection
        Get
            Return ListView1.Columns
        End Get
    End Property
```

And I tried to redraw the control like this:

```
   Me.Invalidate()
   Dim x As New Rectangle With {.X = Me.Location.X, .Y = Me.Location.Y, .Size = Me.Size}
   Me.NotifyInvalidate(x)
```

But for some reasons, its not working. In design time, every time Ii add a column, the corresponding button is not added.

Comment: The code works for the most part.  It's unclear if a button is the same thing as a column header, I assumed it is.  I also guessed that your control is loading a ListView control and not inheriting from it.  I tested on VS2012.

Comment: yes, thats true, i use a listview control, my control just adds some custom style buttons as headers of that listview.. for some reasons, they are not updating in design mode...

Comment: I suggest you edit your post with some of that code on how you are displaying these buttons.

Comment: I would suggest experimenting with IDesignerHost.Activate() and ISelectionService.SetSelectedComponents()

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick idea, might not be the best solution but it doesn't hurt to try and I'm guessing its going to work even if as I said, it is not the best way to do it.

In the Sub you use for Adding/Remove columns, add the following:

```
Dim Graphics As Graphics = [yourform].CreateGraphics
Dim ParamArg As New PaintEventArgs(Graphics, [yourform].ClientRectangle)
InvokePaint(Me, ParamArgs)
```

That shall enforce the nasty thing will paint itself everytime you add/remove.